# Android O Notification for Direct reply message

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-push-notification

We are migrating to Notification Channel system in Android O, we noticed that once Channel is created, it's properties cannot be changed.

We have the following scenario,
- Notification channel is created with,

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
```

/**
     * Higher notification importance: shows everywhere, makes noise and peeks. May use full screen
     * intents.
     */

- we have messaging style with history of messages
- User receives a message in the notification bar - **Notification sound plays**.
- User replies to message, we've implemented BroadcastReceiver to receive replied message and update the notification again with the latest message, But due to the channel importance being High, **notification sound played again** which should not play for better user experience.
- We tried using addHistoricMessage() for the replied message, which shows the same behavior

Is there any way to prevent Android from playing sound for notification for the replied messages.

code:
Channel creation:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = title;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(MESSAGE_CHANNEL, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(android.app.NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

Notification builder:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MESSAGE_CHANNEL);
NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle style = new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(displayName)
                .setConversationTitle(conversation.isGroup() ? conversation.getTitle(context) : null);
style.addMessage(message, timestamp, sender);
.
.
.
.
builder.setStyle(style);
builder.setShowWhen(true);
        builder.setGroup(MESSAGING_GROUP_LABEL);
        builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, conversation.getColorSet().getPrimaryColorId()));
setVisibility(builder);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        setPriority(builder, NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        setCategory(builder, Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);
        setSmallIcon(builder, R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notif);
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(conversation.getConversationId(), notificationId, builder.build());
```

messageRepliedReceiver:
same notification builder is used with previous notificationId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If existing notification is amended with extra message then you can use on the same builder:

```
notificationBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
```

This works even for Notifications in Android O Notification Channels. It will prevent vibration, sound, but it will still peek if Channel setting was Urgent (`IMPORTANCE_HIGH`).

This possible solution was found in this post that has other great ideas about handling "history of messages" notification: [Android: How to use MessagingStyle for notifications without caching messages](https://medium.com/@sidorovroman3/android-how-to-use-messagingstyle-for-notifications-without-caching-messages-c414ef2b816c)

Comment: Thanks Piotr it helped